# Efficiently find sets of pairs of points with similar differences?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to automatically extract analogies from a `word2vec` model in Python. My basic approach is as follows:

1. Enumerate all of the pairs of vectors (n^2) and get their difference.
2. For each difference, add it to every vector (n^3) and find the closest match to the result (n^4).
3. Subtract the difference vector from the closest match and see if we get back to the original test vector, to verify that we have a genuine relationship.

There are some things that can be done to speed this up a bit; if adding a difference to a test vector produces a result that's way off of the unit hypersphere, the closest in-model vector is probably spurious, so we can skip that. And once a relationship has been found, we can skip later re-testing similar differences between all of the pairs that we already added to that relation. But it's still excruciatingly slow!

I know this brute search works in principle, as, having run it for about 12 hours, it does manage to automatically discover analogy sets like `son:grandson::daughter:granddaughter` and less-obvious-but-it-checks-out-when-I-google-the-words ones like `scinax:oreophryne::amalda:gymnobela`. But it takes between several seconds and a few minutes to check every candidate difference, and with over 4 billion vector differences in a model with a 90-ish-thousand-word vocabulary... that will take millions of hours!

So, is there any way to speed this up? Is there a non-brute-force solution to finding natural clusters of similar differences between vectors that might represent coherent analogy sets?